# How to change the default alert sound in GNOME

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, and I want to change the default alert sound from "Drip" to "Sonar". I have tried going into `Settings > Sound > Sound Effects`, however, there is no obvious way of changing the default alter sound, only listening to it, and the other available sounds.

So that is my question, how do I change the default alert sound from "Drip" to "Sonar"? I tried clicking, double-clicking, right-clicking, dragging... Nothing worked...

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: I think just clicking on it make it the default

Comment: @Maythux: I tried clicking, double-clicking, right-clicking, dragging... Nothing worked...

Comment: You can still hear the old sounds after closing the dialogue?

Comment: @A.B.: Yes, I can.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name`

Comment: @A.B.: `'freedesktop'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that what needs to be done for it to change is this:

1. Navigate to *Settings* → *Sound* → *Sound Effects*, and select what you want as the new default:

   [image: Sound settings]
2. Close the window.
3. Restart GDM (will close current session! save your work) with:

   ```
   sudo service gdm restart
   ```

The step I missed was restarting GDM.

Comment: Now it's better =)

Comment: seriously? w/o a warning?!? as soon I ran `sudo service gdm restart` it restarted my session and I lost many works I was doing, now I have to setup everything again... thx vm!!! >:(