# Alert sound doesn't change from default

Tags: sound, 20.04, system-settings

I want to change my alert sound on Ubuntu 20.04 from the default to Glass. I selected Glass in the Settings, I rebooted my computer and ran the command `sudo service gdm restart` (taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/655122/1101910)), but to no avail. The alert sound is still at its default value. I'm testing it by pressing backspace in a newly opened terminal. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I just tested it, it seems that you need to set it to "Default" first, and then select a different sound. So if "Bark" is selected and you change it to "Drip", the terminal still barks. But if you change it to "Default" and then to "Drip", the terminal should drip.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after changing my sound from default to say drip and then installed: unity-tweak-tool...even without opening the teak tool, it seems to have fixed it for me. (looking at the terminal, there are no obvious errors or anything, but happy now it's fixed). update: well haven't rebooted yet...hitting tab in terminal is fixed, haven't rebooted yet but got an email with the old notification sound...hopefully once rebooted it's changed.

Comment: Thank you for informing me of this pretty strange workaround, I would have never thought of this myself :-)